# NP reshape (add extra 2 dimension)

Tags: python, numpy

I will illustrate my question with an example. If I have the array:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
              [9,10,11,12],
              [17,18,19,20],
              [25,26,27,28]])
```

I would like to get

```
array([[[ 1,  2],   [[ 3,  4],
        [9, 10],    [11, 12],
        [17, 18],    [19, 20],
        [25, 26]]    [27, 28]],
```

So apparently if my array was `MxN` , now it will be `Mx(N/2)x2`. How to do it? I tried:

```
import numpy as np

# pre-computed data
data.reshape(data.shape[0], data.shape[1]//2, 2)
```

, does not work as expected

Comment: are you sure in your final output? check the 1st and 2nd rows in each array

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed it.

Comment: I had it right initially, then I edited the question and it "automagically" changed. Anyways,  I have corrected it as should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative solution:

```
out = a.reshape(4, 2, 2).swapaxes(0, 1)
```

out:

```
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 9, 10],
        [17, 18],
        [25, 26]],

       [[ 3,  4],
        [11, 12],
        [19, 20],
        [27, 28]]])
```

Comment: This has the correct dimension and the correct output!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) (on column axis) + [`np.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) combination:

```
arr = np.stack(np.split(a, 2, axis=1))
print(arr)
```

---

```
[[[ 1  2]
  [ 9 10]
  [17 18]
  [25 26]]

 [[ 3  4]
  [11 12]
  [19 20]
  [27 28]]]
```

Comment: Can we somehow add 2 to be the last dimension? bcs currently it is the first one

Comment: @PetarUlev, the answer corresponds to your posted expected output

Comment: Yes, but the dimension is different

Comment: Right now it is 2xMx(N//2)

Comment: I accepted it anyway

Comment: @PetarUlev, post the output in correct shape in that case

Comment: The output does not change. It is simply a matter of notation, but it matters in my case bcs I am going to pass it to a model and it is a practice to put that dimension last

Comment: Maybe I just got confused. I just swapped the dimensions like that: 
np.reshape(X, (X.shape[1], X.shape[2], X.shape[0]))

, but then the output changes. I guess I will stick with your solution. Thanks!